# Xamarin.Forms Shell how to remove the space of the FlyoutItem element in the hamburger menu

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

I am using Shell and I have a design in which I have a FlyoutItem with the FlyoutDisplayOptions property in AsSingleItem, I also have several MenuItem, this design has a page with tabs and a hamburger menu that shows the MenuItem but the problem is that it is empty if I put the title and icon of the entire FlyoutItem item but if I leave it empty, the space does not disappear and is empty, it is a wasted space, my question is how can I remove that space?

That is my code:

```
    <FlyoutItem Route="home" x:Name="flyoutItem"
        FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsSingleItem">
    <ShellContent Route="bottomtab1"
                  Style="{StaticResource TabBackground}"
                  Icon="home_icon"
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:x}" />
    <ShellContent Route="bottomtab2"
                  Style="{StaticResource TabBackground}"
                  Icon="home_icon"
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate DataTemplate views:x}" />
    <ShellContent Route="bottomtab3"
                  Style="{StaticResource TabBackground}"
                  Icon="home_icon"
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate DataTemplate views:x}" />
    <ShellContent Route="bottomtab4"
                  Style="{StaticResource TabBackground}"
                  Icon="home_icon"
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate DataTemplate views:x}" />
    <ShellContent Route="bottomtab5"
                  Style="{StaticResource TabBackground}"
                  Icon="home_icon"
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate DataTemplate views:x}" />
</FlyoutItem>

<MenuItem Text="Test 1"
          IconImageSource="home_icon" />

<MenuItem Text="Test 2"
          IconImageSource="home_icon" />

<MenuItem Text="Test 3"
          IconImageSource="home_icon"/>

<MenuItem Text="Test 4"
          IconImageSource="home_icon"/>

<MenuItem Text="Test 5"
          IconImageSource="home_icon"/>

<MenuItem Text="Test 6"
          IconImageSource="home_icon"/>
```

I leave in these images the design

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove the item in the FlyoutItem, but it still was show in the MainPage.Like following GIF.
[image]

First of all remove the content of `FlyoutItem`. Then just use `TabBar` for all of the `ShellContent` like following code.

```
  <TabBar>
    <Tab Title="Browse" Icon="tab_feed.png">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ItemsPage}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="About" Icon="tab_about.png">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AboutPage}" />
    </Tab>
  </TabBar>
```

But If you hide it, when your click the any MenuItem, you will not come back to the homePage(show aminials information).(For example, my homePage will show aminials information, when i click the `About` MenuItem, I cannot access my aminials page like following GIF),

[image]

So, I advice you give a title and icon for your `FlyoutItem`, when you click other MenuItems, you can back to the previous homePage.Here is running GIF.
[image]

Comment: can i remove the icon and icon space of Flyout item ?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar scenario - I had several pages that only should be viewed based on startup logic, and I needed the shell to load them in the correct order, but also not be visible in the flyout. I was able to do this just by adding the pages that should be hidden from the flyout in hierarchal order as `FlyoutItem`s with `IsEnabled="True"` and is `IsVisible="False"` attributes. From the [xamarin docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout)

> IsEnabled, of type boolean, defines if the item is selectable in the chrome.
>
> IsVisible, of type bool, indicates if the FlyoutItem is hidden on the
> flyout menu. Its default value is true.

- When I only set `IsVisible` to false, I am pretty certain I was still able to click the flyout item where it would have been even though it wasn't visibly there. So that is why I also set the `IsEnabled` to false. It may be the case only `IsVisible=False` is required.

When the app runs the `MainPage=new AppShell()` and it will load the `CheckConnection` page (now hidden from the flyout) first which has logic to navigate to the correct page (Remember, as @Leon Lu - MSFT said in his answer, to make sure sure you can still navigate correctly to and from "hidden" pages).

```
<FlyoutItem 
        IsEnabled="True"
        IsVisible="False"
        Title="CheckConnectionPage"
        >
    <ShellContent Route="CheckConnectionPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:CheckConnectionPage}"  />
    
</FlyoutItem>
<FlyoutItem 
        IsEnabled="True"
        IsVisible="False"
        Title="StatPage"
        >
    <ShellContent Route="StatPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:StatPage}"  />
</FlyoutItem>

<FlyoutItem Title="Configuration" Icon="settings_icon_black.png">
    <ShellContent Route="ConfigurePage"  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ConfigurePage}" />
</FlyoutItem>
```

The result is that only the Configuration page is available to tap on in the Flyout, and there is no spacing, and there is no invisible place that a user can accidently click on to cause shell navigation (as is the case if you have a clickable "space" that is an invisible shell flyout item).

[image]

You should be able to remove the whitespace from the `<FlyoutItem Route="home"...` `FlyoutItem` by adding the same attributes.

Comment: Thanks, this really helped me. I set my init/loading page to "IsVisible=False". It is displayed initially (correct), but doesn't show up in the menu. Great!